# Insert into second column after specific id into csv

Tags: php, mysql, csv, export-to-csv, mysql-5.7

I have a table named `A` with 1000 rows Like:

```
id  |  name
----+------
1   |  a
2   |  b
3   |  c
4   |  d
```

and so on until `id=1000`

Now I want to export this table `A` as `CSV` which i am able to do. But I want data in 2 columns like data till `id=499` should print in 1st column and remaining data should print in second column. And i am not printing `id` in `CSV`.

Result should be like this in `CSV`:

```
a   |  at500   (I am using 500 for reference that from here it should print in 2nd column)
b   |  bvf501
c499|  vf1000
```

This is the code i have till now which print all rows into single column:

```
$filename = "excelfilename";
$sep = "\t";

$sql = "Select `name` from `A`";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . 
mysqli_error($con). "<br>" . mysql_errno());    
$file_ending = "xls";
//header info for browser
header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
    $schema_insert = "";
    for($j=0; $j<mysqli_num_fields($result);$j++)
    {
        if(!isset($row[$j]))
            $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
        elseif ($row[$j] != "")
            $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;

        else
            $schema_insert .= "".$sep;

    }

    $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert .= "\t";
    print(trim($schema_insert));
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: What is the code you have so far that does not suit your needs?

Comment: @sorak updated the code in question

Answer (score 0):

First you can read the data from DB and keep the result in an array.

Consider, $full_data_array is your 1000 'name'

Then you can split the array into two(since you need 500 each) like this,

```
$chunk_array = array_chunk($full_data_array, 2);
```

You will get multidimensional numerically indexed array.

Combine those two array like this,

```
$combined_array = array_map(function ($a1, $a2) { return $a1 . ' , ' . $a2; } , $chunk_array[0], $chunk_array[1]);
```

Then loop through this $combined_array to create the CSV like this,

```
$file = fopen("your_csv_name.csv","w");
foreach ($combined_array as $line)
  {
  fputcsv($file,explode(',',$line));
  }
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$filename = "excelfilename";
$sep = "\t";

$sql = "Select `name` from `A`";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . 
mysqli_error($con). "<br>" . mysql_errno());    
$file_ending = "xls";
//header info for browser
header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");

$tempData="";
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
    $tempData=$row;
}   

$size=count($tempData)/2;
for($i=0;$i<$size;$i++){
    $schema_insert1 = "";
    for($j=0; $j<count($tempData[$i]);$j++)
    {
        if(!isset($tempData[$i][$j]))
            $schema_insert1 .= "NULL".$sep;
        elseif ($tempData[$i][$j] != "")
            $schema_insert1 .= $tempData[$i][$j].$sep;

        else
            $schema_insert1 .= "".$sep;

    }

    $schema_insert2 = "";
    for($j=0; $j<count($tempData[$i+$size]);$j++)
    {
        if(!isset($tempData[$i+$size][$j]))
            $schema_insert2 .= "NULL".$sep;
        elseif ($tempData[$i+$size][$j] != "")
            $schema_insert2 .= $tempData[$i+$size][$j].$sep;

        else
            $schema_insert2 .= "".$sep;

    }

    $schema_insert1 = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert1);
    $schema_insert2 = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert2);

    // Now concatenation them both strings as you want
    // $tempString .= $schema_insert1.$sep.$schema_insert2;
}
```

Replace or alter `// $tempString .= $schema_insert1.$sep.$schema_insert2;` this line with your requirement.

Hope this work for you.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: tempString

Comment: insert this line at the start of the loop $tempString="";

Comment: Or just before using it

Comment: I'm really sorry I forgot to add $tempData[$i][$j] this in nested loops

Comment: I had updated my code please check it and let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '+', expecting ']'  on "$tempData[$i][$j]" so i removed "". But getting empty sheet

Comment: On which line you are getting this error? Can you post this line so I can identify syntax error.

Comment: on this line  $schema_insert2 .= "$tempData[$i+$size][$j]".$sep;

Comment: Sorry to say. If you focus on these two lines  $schema_insert1 .= "$tempData[$i][$j]".$sep; and $schema_insert2 .= "$tempData[$i+$size][$j]".$sep; you can easily identify error by yourself. $tempData[$i][$j] is variable and accidentally I put double cotes around it. If you remove these cotes it starts working.

Comment: For easiness I updated the code above. If you can't understand yet, then copy and past above code. Now it is working

Comment: Sir i already checked code by removing double cotes but i am getting empty sheet